# Add a variable to href in a 'for' loop

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var meun = document.createElement("div");

    meun.setAttribute('id', i);
    meun.setAttribute("style", "width:70px; height:70px; background:url(archive/" + i + ".jpg); background-size: 70px 70px; float:left; margin-top:10px; opacity:1");
    document.body.appendChild(frame);
    document.getElementById("frame").appendChild(meun);

    meun.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.location.href = "i+'.html'"
    }, false);
}
```

The problem I have is in `addEventListener`: how to pass the variable `i` into the `href`? I guess it is a problem of syntax.

Comment: better avoid using ids starting with numbers and being numbers, use letters or underscores instead, same for classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only a syntax problem, you also need a closure:

```
(function(x) {
    meun.addEventListener('click', function(){window.location.href = x + '.html'}, false);
})(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the variable `i`, don't put it in quotes, which would mean literally the letter "i":

```
meun.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.location.href = i + '.html';
}, false);
```

Comment: As bfavaretto pointed out, you also need a closure. Otherwise i == 8 for all handlers.

Comment: When menu's item will be clicked, `i` will be equal to `8`, so your code will always end up with `window.location.href = '8.html';`.

Comment: @Engineer that is a different problem than the one specified in the question. Refer to bfavaretto's answer.

Comment: @jbabey Yes,that's different problem. But your code, just like OP's code are equally incorrect, as does not solve a problem.